# How to make a cron job in App Engine that targets a service and a version?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, cron

I want to have a cron job that calls my endpoint at a certain services and version (App Engine).

I have created a cron job with the following config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cronentries>
    <cron>
        <url>/CleanupRealtimeDatabase</url>
        <target>dev-dot-admin</target>
        <description>Cleanup Realtime Database (Dev)</description>
        <schedule>every 24 hours</schedule>
    </cron>
</cronentries>
```

This will make a call to http://dev-dot-admin.myapp.appspot.com/CleanupRealtimeDatabase

This doesn't work, because it can not combine the -dot- and the .

So the only solution is to use -dot- twice or use . twice. I can't control the second dot in the url (it's not part of the config). But when I change the dot to . in my config above I get the following error:

> Bad configuration: XML error validating  
>       
>           /CleanupRealtimeDatabase
>           dev.admin
>           Cleanup Realtime Database (Dev)
>           every 24 hours
>          against /Users/user/sdk/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/java/docs/cron.xsd
>   Caused by: cvc-pattern-valid: Value 'dev.admin' is not facet-valid
>   with respect to pattern '[a-z\d-]{1,100}' for type 'target-Type'.

Not sure how to solve this? It feels like a bug in App Engine tooling.

Answer (score 2):

This won't work as the (single) service version that will receive the targeted cron requests is not under the cron configuration control. From the  row in the [Cron job definitions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/cronref#cron_job_definitions) (emphasis mine):

> The **target** string is prepended to your app's hostname. It is
>   usually the name of a service. **The cron job will be routed to the
>   version of the named service that is configured for traffic**.
>
> **Warning:** Be careful if you run a cron job with [traffic splitting](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/splitting-traffic) enabled. The request from the cron job is always sent
>   from the same IP address, so if you've specified IP address splitting,
>   the logic will route the request to the same version every time. If
>   you've specified cookie splitting, the request will not be split at
>   all, because there is no cookie accompanying the request.
>
> **If the service name that is specified for `target` is not found, then the Cron request is routed to either the `default` service, or to
>   the version of your app that is configured to receive traffic**. For
>   more information about routing, see [How Requests are Routed](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/how-requests-are-routed).

But since the cron service is nothing more than `GET` requests sent according to the schedule you could have a single generic cron config and, inside its handler, issue yourself more specific HTTP(S) requests to any URLs you desire.

You could use the [`apps.services.versions`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps.services.versions) API in order to dynamically build the correct list of these per service-version pair URLs.